# Supabase array column includes any element of another array

Tags: javascript, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I'm trying to filter my supabase blogposts depending on if they have a tag that is included in the current post tags. Basically, i want a 'related' posts component.

The blog has a `tags` column (an array of strings).

I'm trying this, but it comes empty:

```
  const { data: relatedPosts, error: relatedPostsError } = await supabase
    .from("post")
    .select(
      "title, description, likes, cover_image, views, slug, created_at, published_date, published, id, tags, created_by ( name, profile_image, default_profile_img_color, id, description, username, cafecito, is_verified )"
    )
    .eq("published", true)
    .neq("id", post.id)
    .contains("tags", post.tags)
    .order("published_date", { ascending: false })
    .limit(12);
```

I've also tried the `containedBy` operator

Comment: What if you use async/await?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `overlaps()` filter? It will pull up any rows that has any common tags with the current post being displayed.

```js
const { data: relatedPosts, error: relatedPostsError } = await supabase
    .from("post")
    .select(
      "title, description, likes, cover_image, views, slug, created_at, published_date, published, id, tags, created_by ( name, profile_image, default_profile_img_color, id, description, username, cafecito, is_verified )"
    )
    .eq("published", true)
    .neq("id", post.id)
    .overlaps("tags", post.tags)
    .order("published_date", { ascending: false })
    .limit(12);
```

You can read more about it on the docs here:
https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/overlaps